# Doing a specific comparison along the columns of two matricies

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have two numpy matricies of the same shape.
In one of them each column contains all 0's except for a 1. 
In the other matrix each column contains random numbers.

My goal is to count the number of columns for which the position of the 1 in the column of the first matrix corresponds with the position of the highest element in the column of the second matrix.

For example:

```
 a = [[1,0],
      [0,1]]
 b = [[2,3],
      [3,5]]
 myFunc(a,b)
```

would yield 1 since the argmax of the first column in b is not the same as in a but it is the same in the second column.

My solution was to iterate over the columns and check if the argmax was the same, store that in a list and then sum that at the end, but this doesn't take advantage of numpy's fastness. Is there a faster way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to tell with this small sample, but would something like this work? `np.sum(a.argmax(axis=0)==b.argmax(axis=0))`

Comment: Sorry for the small sample, and your answer works!  I never knew you could use axis in argmax! Post it as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This checks the indices of max in each column of `b` against indices of 1s in corresponding column of `a` and counts the matches:

```
(a.T.nonzero()[1]==b.argmax(axis=0)).sum()
```

output in your example:

```
1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer however, when I use a=np.array([[1,2,3],[2,2,3],[1,3,4]]) and 
b=np.array([[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,1]]) and then run (np.where(a)[1]==b.argmax(axis=0)).sum(), I get an error saying elementwise comparison failed. Maybe it is a small syntax error?

Comment: @BOSSrobot I edited the answer shortly after posting. Please use the latest version of post. You also mislabeled your arrays. `a` and `b` should be swapped based on your definition in the question (i.e. `b=np.array([[1,2,3],[2,2,3],[1,3,4]])` and `a=np.array([[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,1]])`). Once you swap them, this answer works and returns 2. This is also similar to answer suggested in comments, however, I expect nonzero to be faster than argmax.

Comment: My bad, your answer works and I can also see why it would be faster than argmax! One thing I don't understand is that the code still works without a.T.nonzero() and instead with a.nonzero() but i think that is because a.T() is not in place. Anyways, thanks for your help!

Comment: @BOSSrobot You are welcome. If I am not wrong, you would still need `.T`. I am guessing you are trying it on a square matrix that would result in the same indices with or without `.T`. Try it on a non square matrix to see which one is the right one you want.Thank you

Comment: You are right, that is very interesting. I think I misinterpreted the nonzero function. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Given that there will only be a single `1` in the first array, then you should just be able to compare where the `argmax` is at the same position

```
def myfunc(binary_array,value_array):
    return np.sum(a.argmax(axis=1)==b.argmax(axis=1))

a = np.array([[1,0],
     [0,1]])
b = np.array([[2,3],
     [3,5]])

myfunc(a,b)
1

c=np.array([[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,1]])
d=np.array([[1,2,3],[2,2,3],[1,3,4]]) 

myfunc(c,d)
1

e=np.array([[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,1]])
f=np.array([[1,2,3],[2,2,3],[1,3,4]]) 

myfunc(e,f)
2
```